# How to call JavaScript code on multiple DIV elements without the ID attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Sorted out. Thanks to everyone who helped me** How to call JavaScript code on multiple DIV elements on the page, when the id attribute is missing (or when it is not allowed to call an individual element, for some reason).

I want to be able to perform some action on each element by changing the background color (content) and color of the **h tag** (where it was clicked), but I don't want to access each element individually.

```js
Object.entries('.Container').map(( object ) => {
          object[1].addEventListener("click", function() {

               // Output innerHTML of the clicked element
               console.log("Hello " + this +  " (" + this.innerHTML + ") from map method...");
          });
     });
```

```css
  body {
               background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
               margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
               height: 100vh; width: 100%;
               display: flex; flex-direction: column;
               align-items: center; justify-content: center;
               overflow: hidden;
          }
          .Container {
              background-color: lightgray;
              margin: 0; padding: 0;
              height: auto; width: 250px;
              display: flex; flex-direction: column;
              align-items: center; justify-content: center;
              overflow: hidden; 
          
          }
          .content {
              background-color: lightcyan;
              margin: 5px; padding: 0;
              height: auto; width: 80%;
              display: flex; flex-direction: row;
              align-items: center; justify-content: center;
              overflow: hidden; 
          
          }
          h3 {
               color: red;
          }
```

```html
  <div class="Container">
          <div class ="content"><h3>content 1</h3></div>
          <div class ="content"><h3>content 2</h3></div>
          <div class ="content"><h3>content 3</h3></div>
     </div>
```

***Final resolution:***

```js
toggleClassAddEVent();
triggerOutsideElement();

// Call   multiple DIV elements without the ID attribute
function toggleClassAddEVent() {
     for (const content of document.querySelectorAll('.Container > .content')) {
          content.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
               event.stopPropagation();
               $(content).addClass('Active').siblings('.content').removeClass('Active');
               content.children[0].textContent = 'changed text';
              // console.log("Hello " + content.outerHTML + ")...");
          });
          
          triggerOutsideElement();

     }
}
// (Optional) Remove class 'Active' from all 'Active' elements when clicking outside the elements that contain the class 'Active'
function triggerOutsideElement() {
     
     $(document).click(function (e) {Hide_elementsByClickingOutSideOfThem(e);});
     
     function Hide_elementsByClickingOutSideOfThem(e) {
       
          var content = $(e.target).closest(".content").attr("class");
          if (content === "content") {
               console.log("Return True: This belongs to the content class");
          } else {
               console.log("Return false: This does not belong to the content class");
               $('.content').removeClass('Active');
          }
     }
      
}
```

```css
body {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
     margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
     height: 100vh; width: 100%;
     display: flex; flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center; justify-content: center;
     overflow: hidden;
}


.Container {
     background-color: lightgray;
     margin: 10px; padding: 0;
     height: auto; width: 250px;
     display: flex; flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center; justify-content: center;
 
 }
 .content {
     background-color: lightcyan;
     margin: 5px; padding: 0;
     height: auto; width: 80%;
     display: flex; flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center; justify-content: center;
     position: relative;
 }
 .PopUp {
      display: none;
 }
 
 .Active {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
 }
 .textContent {
      color: red;
 }
 
 .Active  .textContent {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
 }
 .Active .PopUp {
      display: flex;
      background-color: lightcoral;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 40px;
      width: 150px;
      position: absolute; z-index: 10;
      top: 0; left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container">
          <div class ="content">
               <h3 class="textContent" >content 1</h3>
               <div class="PopUp">
                    <span>PopUp 1</span>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class ="content">
               <h3 class="textContent" >content 2</h3>
               <div class="PopUp">
                    <span>PopUp 2</span>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class ="content">
               <h3 class="textContent" >content 3</h3>
               <div class="PopUp">
                    <span>PopUp 3</span>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query string `.container > .content` to match elements which have a class name of `content` which are children of an element with a class name of `container`:

```js
for (const content of document.querySelectorAll('.Container > .content')) {
  content.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    content.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    content.children[0].textContent = 'changed text';
    console.log("Hello " + content.outerHTML + ")...");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>content 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>content 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>content 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that `.map` should only be used for constructing a new array. If you're not going to construct a new array, use something else. For side effects (like attaching listeners), use `forEach` or a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. Just one more thing like being able to trigger a toggle class for the clicked element without changing the others that were not clicked?

Comment: The `content` variable is the clicked element, so you can call `classList.toggle` on it. `content.classList.toggle('foo')`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Because the event.stopPropagation (e) event doesn't work in this case, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `stopPropagation` will successfully stop the propagation of the event, but in this snippet, there are no other event listeners, so what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: When I clicked outside the 'Container' class it would remove all classes like: $ ('. PopUp'). RemoveClass ('Active');
      $ ('. content'). removeClass ('Active');

Comment: Make sure you're using the same event type. The snippet is using a click listener, so make sure your outer listener is listening to clicks as well, and it should work.

Comment: I put it in the 'content.addEventListener' but I couldn't. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `Object.entries()` has to be an object, not a string. What you want is `document.querySelectorAll()`, which returns a list of all the elements matching the selector. Since you want to click on the `<h3>` buttons, you need to extend the selector to match them.

You also should use `forEach()` rather than `map()`. `map()` is used when you want to return a new array containing the result of calling a function on the original array. If you just want to perform actions on the array elements, you don't need to return a new array.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.Container > .content > h3').forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Output innerHTML of the clicked element
    console.log("Hello " + this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>content 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>content 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>content 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```